# What defines an observation in AIC?

Tags: model-selection, likelihood, aic

I have a question based upon a section of this paper: "Model selection for dynamical systems via sparse regression and information criteria", which can be found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01773

It states the following:[image]

My question is: How can the sum over each time series residual be called average error (no division) and how can that be used in place of the likelihood function? How is this mathematically sound?

Comment: I think the number of observations used in AIC has to be the number of *statistically independent* observations. Without having read the rest of the paper, I'm guessing that the rest of the time series is a deterministic function of, and therefore statistically *dependent* on, a random initial condition, but many initial conditions are used.

Comment: Correct, 100 initial conditions are being used. They are dependent, because of a constant term in the equation, right? All other terms should only include transformations of the current state variables in this way:
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{d}{dt}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 \\
 x_2
 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_2 \\
 a_0+a_1*x_1+a2*x_2+a_3*cos(x_1) ...
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
So no further past data points etc.

Comment: @korrok So you are telling me that the likelihood function is not the multiplication of normal distributions of residuals in this case? That would also mean that the parameters are not the ML parameters after linear regression.

Answer (score 1):

@Oarz There is a typo in the $E_{avg}$ equation. It should be divided by the number of points in the time series so that it is the average error at each time-point for that time series. This is correct in the GitHub implementation of the code available here: https://github.com/niallmm/SINDy_AIC/%E2%80%8B

As for your main question, we are treating each time series as an observation, rather than each point in the time series. We take many initial conditions. For these synthetic examples, the observation error at each time point is drawn from a Gaussian distribution. So for the correct model, the residuals at each point are Gaussian and the average error on each time series is also Gaussian. The only assumption needed to substitute into AIC for the likelihood function is that the error is Gaussian. In practice, the error for the incorrect models will not be Gaussian, but it will be "worse" than Gaussian so the AIC will still have the correct trend. I found (through numerical experiment) that taking each time point as an observation did not work well but do not have a rigorous explanation as to why this happens.

Usually, AIC is used on in-sample data (ie the same as the training data), not out f sample data. For most of the examples shown most of the AIC value is coming from the effect of out-of-sample cross-validation, not the AIC penalty. However, for a small number of time series (observations) the penalty does matter.

It may be that other methods such as minimum descriptive length would be more mathematically rigorous for use on time-series, but I have not performed the comparison of actual performance.

Comment: Thank you! This already was very helpful. One more thing. Can you tell me where in Burnhams Book it is explained that the RSS can be used in your way for an approximation of the Likelihood function? Your approach then only works, when I have a larger set of (random?) initial conditions, right? So if I am stuck with one experimental time series it becomes hard to use? Sorry for asking these simple questions. I am a mechanical engineering student, not mathematics :)

Comment: yes. If you only have one time series, then I would not recommend using the framework we used. In that case you only have one "sample". Based on my experience with the numerical experiments I would not expect treating each time-point as a measurement in the AIC framework to work, unfortunately. Burnham and Anderson do not show that you can use RSS in the way I do. They just show the connection between general RSS and the likelihood function.